# copy from one table field to another table field in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, copy

With phpmyadmin how can I copy the text from a field called products_folder which is located in a table called description to a field called products_us which is located in a table called products_description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO `products_description ` (`products_us `) SELECT `products_folder ` FROM `description `
```

Comment: answer updated ... try it and see if it is what you're looking for

Comment: It didnt work, I modified it a bit to make it do something but it created double fields. INSERT INTO products_description (products_us) SELECT products_folder FROM products